# Lookup for a referenced document in an array of embedded documents

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, lookup

I got two collections.
One contains an array of objects. These objects own a field with an id to a document in another collection.
The goal is to "replace" the ref by the document. Sounds simple but I have no clue how to archive this.

E.G.

**Collection "Product"**

```
{ "_id": 1,
  "alias": "ProductA"
},
{ "_id": 2,
  "alias": "ProductC"
}
```

**Collection "Order"**

```
{ "_id": 5765,
  "cart": [
    {
      "product": 1,
      "qty": 7
    }, {
      "product": 2,
      "qty": 6
    }
  ]
}
```

What I need by a query is this:

```
{ "_id": 5765,
  "cart": [
    {
      "product": {
        "_id": 1,
        "alias": "ProductA"
      },
      "qty": 7
    }, {
      "product": {
        "_id": 2,
        "alias": "ProductC"
      },
      "qty": 6
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried a simple lookup, but the array will only contains the products. What do I need to change?

```
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "products",
        let: {
            tmp: "$cart.product"
        },
        pipeline: [
            {
                $match: {
                    $expr: {
                        $in: ["$_id", "$$tmp"]
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        as: "cart.product"
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a new `$addFields` stage to transform the output from the `$lookup` stage - it gets the desired output:

```
db.order.aggregate([
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "product",
        let: {
            tmp: "$cart.product"
        },
        pipeline: [
            {
                $match: {
                    $expr: {
                        $in: ["$_id", "$$tmp"]
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        as: "products"
    }
},
{ 
    $addFields: {
         cart: {
             $map: {
                 input: "$cart", as: "ct",
                 in: {
                     product: {
                         $arrayElemAt: [ 
                             { $filter: {
                                   input: "$products", as: "pr",
                                   cond: {
                                      $eq: [ "$$ct.product", "$$pr._id" ]
                                   }
                              }
                          }, 0 ]
                     },
                     qty: "$$ct.qty"
                 }
             }
         }
    }
}
] ).pretty()
```

Comment: Hum... There is a small "mistake". The "product" in "cart" is an array with one element. How can I unwind this?!

Comment: Yes, you are right; I didn't notice it. I fixed it and updated the code. There is no need to _unwind_ as there is only one element in he array - just get the first element.